# How to compute a p-value for the Pearson correlation in R?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, pearson-r

Is it possible to find the p-value in pearson correlation in R?

To find the pearson correlation, I usually do this

```
col1 = c(1,2,3,4)
col2 = c(1,4,3,5)
cor(col1,col2)
# [1] 0.8315218
```

But how I can find the p-value of this?

Comment: The help on `cor` (`?cor`) *explicitly* mentions `cor.test` (under "See Also")

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you can use `cor.test` :

```
col1 = c(1,2,3,4) 
col2 = c(1,4,3,5)
cor.test(col1,col2)
```

which gives :

```
# Pearson's product-moment correlation   
# data:  col1 and col2   
# t = 2.117, df = 2, p-value = 0.1685   
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0   
# 95 percent confidence interval:   
#  -0.6451325  0.9963561   
# sample estimates:   
#       cor    
# 0.8315218
```

More information about the statistics and extra parameters at the official page:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.test.html

Comment: thanks, not enough points to upvote, used it though

Answer (score 10):

If you want only the P value:

```
> cor.test(col1,col2)$p.value
[1] 0.1684782
```

Comment: However, isn't cor.test a paired correlation test, different from cor (an independent samples correlation test)?

Answer (score 8):

The following will do as you ask:

```
 library(Hmisc) # You need to download it first.
 rcorr(x, type="pearson") # type can be pearson or spearman
```

Here x is a data frame, and rcorr returns every correlation which it is possible to form from the "x" data frame.

Or you could calculate the statistic yourself:

$$
t = \frac{\hat{\rho}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-\hat{\rho}^2}{n-2}}}
$$

Where $\hat{\rho}$ is the pearson correlation estimated from the data, and n is the sample size.

Comment: Thanks, but what is x ? I think it's some concatenation of col1 and col2 because we need two vectors to calculate pearson correlation. But can you tell me what x is?

Comment: It is a data frame, see my update.